# Identify the set of points which satisfy $ |z|=\text{Re}z+1 $

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $ z=x+iy $

I want to Identify the set of points that satisfy $ |z|=\text{Re}z+1 $.

Here's what I have found:

$ \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=x+1\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\iff $

$ x^{2}+y^{2}=\left(x+1\right)^{2}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\iff $

$ y^{2}-2x-1=0\thinspace $

Now how can I identify the set of points based on the equation? I tried to use desmos, it looks like hyperbola, but its not. So im not sure...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, the equation $|z|=\text{Re}(z)+1 $ indicates that the horizontal distance from $z$ to the vertical line $x=-1$ is equal to its distance to the origin, which defines the parabola with the focus at the origin and the directrix $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the equation is $y^2 = 2x + 1$. This gives us $x = \frac{y^2 - 1}{2}$. This is a parabola because $x$ is a quadratic function of $y$.